# How to apply a class to a specified grouping of characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to reduce the HTML in a document by applying a class to a very specific group of characters. In my example it is to a group of asterisks, they appear in the document as ** and the code that they are wrapped in is

```
<span class="asterisk">**</span>
```

But there are over 50 instances on the page. So I am looking for a way to have the class added dynamically to a defined group, in this case `**`

Thus far the most efficient solution that has been suggested was

```
<script>
  $("span:contains('**')").addClass("asterisk");
</script>
```

which reduces the amount of code needed and brings it to `<span>**</span>`

In the example below if I wanted all '**' to indicate food items and be given a class I could do

```
<span>**</span>Indicates food related word
<p>Intelligentsia high life shoreditch keffiyeh skateboard, hoodie master cleanse helvetica. Fanny pack <span>**</span>raw denim street art, wes anderson gentrify lomo lo-fi. </p>
<p>Selfies typewriter you probably haven't heard of them <span>**</span>small batch street art, cliche raw denim try-hard sartorial cardigan pitchfork. Forage flannel portland, small batch before they sold out +1 post-ironic <span>**</span>PBR skateboard mixtape fap try-hard banjo bicycle rights. Vinyl banksy banjo, <span>**</span>gastropub <span>**</span>four loko art party <span>**</span>food truck next level.</p>
```

See how that can get repetitive? So My intent is to just type in the '**' next to what I want selected. And then the class be dynamically added to a defined grouping of characters.

```
<p>**Chambray letterpress **kale **chips **high life 90's wolf yr semiotics mcsweeney's biodiesel, flannel fixie retro.</p> 
<p>Meh wayfarers fap scenester retro single-origin **coffee, cliche craft **beer 8-bit lo-fi selvage yr mixtape 90's.</p>
```

Could use some help narrowing down where to go from here to finish this up.

Comment: Your question has some conflicting information. Are the `span` tags already present in your markup, or do you want to add them? Do you want to add a class to existing tags, or add tags? Why are you using `td` selectors? What does your initial markup actually look like, and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: You can't nest double quotes without escaping the inner quotes. The JavaScript code will crash. It's simpler to replace the inner or outer quotes with single quotes: `'<span class="asterisk">**</span>'`.

Comment: @apsillers my intent was to remove the existing span tags, then dynamically have the "**" wrapped with spans containing a class of "asterisk"

Answer (score 2):

The clearest way to use [`.addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) is simply to specify the class name(s) you want to add:

```
$("span:contains('**')").addClass("asterisk");
```

`addClass` can accept a function, but that is an advanced use, for when you want to treat each element in a jQuery set differently. Since you want to do the same thing to each element, `.addClass` does not need a function.

Comment: @7stud Agreed. A second look reveals that there's quite a bit of conflicting information.

Comment: I am saying that I tried various ways, hence the various examples. Not trying to replace a class, I am attempting to have a class dynamically added when a string matches the value I input, in this case "**"

Comment: This actually worked great. What I should clear up was asking that I wanted to see if it was possible to target that specific string without even needed a span wrapped around the '**' ?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing quotes incorrectly, and strings are immutable, so `String.replace` does not alter the original string; it returns a new one.

```
value = value.replace('**', '<span class="asterisk">**</span>');
// Now you need to actually do something with value
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you wrote exactly what I was looking for, I wrapped it in a script tag, but not sure what else I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to replace the class name, you can do this:

```
$("span.some_class").addClass( function(index, current_class) {
     return current_class + ' new_class' 
});
```

If you want to change the class name instead of adding to it, you can eliminate current_class from the return value.

Comment: You are technically correct, my mistake was in how I presented what my intent was. I was basically attempting to see if I could target a specified string and dynamically add a class to it.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working best while minimizing code input was

```
  <script>
    var value = $(document.body).html(),
    re = /\*\*/g;
    str = value.replace(re, '<span class="asterisk">**</span>');
    $(document.body).html(str);
  </script>
```

This saves a future person inputting content from having to remember to add a `<span>` to the **

Hopefully this was beneficial to others to add to their projects to style strings according to your needs.